# Преобразование текущего времени в заданный

Tags: c++, linux

Как можно преобразовать из текущего времени в заданный?! Суть моей проблемы, мне надо чтобы вместо текущего месяца выводил следующий. Имеется ввиду: "07"->"08".

```
const string currentDateTime() {
    time_t now = time(0);
    struct tm  tstruct;
    char buf[80];
    tstruct = *localtime(&now);
    strftime(buf, sizeof(buf), "%Y-%m-%d.%X", &tstruct);
    return buf;
    //cout << "Текущее время на сервере: " << currentDateTime() << endl;
}

// Пробовал так реализовать, но не удалось. 
    for(int i=0; i<sizeof(buf); i++)
    {
        buf[i+6] += k;
    }
    return buf;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Чуток подправляете структуру и выводите.

```
// g++ -Wall month.cpp
# include <time.h>
# include <string>
# include <iostream>
const std::string currentDateTime() {
    time_t now = time(0);
    struct tm  tstruct;
    char buf[80];
    tstruct = *localtime(&now);

        tstruct .   tm_mon = ( tstruct  .   tm_mon + 1 ) % 12 ;
        if  (   tstruct .   tm_mon == 0 ) ++ tstruct    .   tm_year ;

    strftime(buf, sizeof(buf), "%Y-%m-%d.%X", &tstruct);        
    return buf;
}

int main() {
    std::cout << "Текущее время на сервере: " << currentDateTime() << std::endl;
}
```

Comment: Спасибо большое. Не додумался  об этом.